# Sed Unable to Update image with ${GITHUB_RUN_ID}

Tags: github-actions, continuous-deployment

I am running a github actions workflow, and I would like to understand why is the `sed` command unable to inject the GITHUB_RUN_ID in the second command below?

```
- name: Set ${GITHUB_RUN_ID}
  run: echo "${GITHUB_RUN_ID}" > .github/workflows/run_id

- name: Wait for ${GITHUB_RUN_ID}
  run: wait

- name: Update k8s manifest with new image
  run: |
       cd base/base
       sed -i 's/image *= (.)/image: gitauwairimu/javamvn:${GITHUB_RUN_ID}/g' deployment.yaml
       cat deployment.yaml
```

The step: `name: Set ${GITHUB_RUN_ID}` echos the variable but the second doesn't catch on? Why and what can be done about it?

Comment: Shell variables don't expand in single quotes. Use double quotes instead.

Comment: You can simply use [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) instead of `sed` to work with YAML files.

Comment: @Azeem I tried the double quotes and then the yq command: yq -i '.image = "gitauwairimu/javamvn:${GITHUB_RUN_ID}"' deployment.yaml            I get same results as before.

Comment: Double quotes were for the `sed` command. `yq` has different syntax. For `yq`, you may find multiple SO threads how to do that or dive into its docs.

Comment: Also, looks like you haven't tested that `sed` locally. You're using `/` as part of your substitution but the image name itself has one i.e. `gitauwairimu/javamvn`. So, you need to switch it to something else e.g. `|`. Example: `sed -i "s|image: .*|image: gitauwairimu/javamvn:${GITHUB_RUN_ID}|g" deployment.yaml`

Comment: This did it: sed -i "s|image: .*|image: gitauwairimu/javamvn:${GITHUB_RUN_ID}|g" deployment.yaml
Thanks @Azeem #CI/CD Collective